# Prevent text-copying, even through element inspection

Tags: web, copy-paste

I need to know if it's possible to not only prevent webusers copying a body of text (I know this already), but also how to prevent them from just pulling it from the element inspection tool?

Answer (score 1):

Not Possible, since all website file will be downloaded to user's computer
they can read + copy whatever they want

Comment: So not even using an iframe will help?

Comment: It's can protect from beginner user, however if your objective is 100% protect, then the answer is no